# Better model for CoreData when there are huge amounts of fields and intensive update during synchronization

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm recently having a big headache in my app:

In my application, each of the units has almost 100 attributes to keep, and some of them may be updated very frequently, even tens or more updates per unit in a few second during initial synchronisation. As putting them all together in one table can be very inefficient, and there are some of them which are more likely  to be resynchronized, I tried to break the unit to 5 - 6 smaller tables according to the functionality and possible update frequency, each of them has 8 - 32 fields and one more for primary key. To prevent main thread from blocking, I made an background context to update the data as well. Whenever `context.save()` is called, the main context is merged with the background context.

However when I try to do the batch testing, let's say about 50 units in the table, I find that the UI is still seriously blocked because the main context (which is responsible for fetching UI layout according to units attributes in the database) is busying at merging with intensive background context update.

I also found that there are more 10000 merging when reloading data even if there are only 50 units, I looked into it and found that whenever one `context.save()` is called, my app gets up to 9 `NSManagedObjectContextDidSave` notifications, which means most of the merging are actually redundant.

I'm also wondering if there is better way (in both context management or data table normalization design's perspective) to deal with the database structure problem: while the amount of records is not huge (probably less than 1000 in total), but have quite a lot of fields to maintain. The technique for manipulating huge records are already mature enough to improve efficiency, but as for dealing with huge fields, I can find very limited resources, not to mention resources in CoreData.

Not sure if changing to periodically context saving is a good idea because it's a bluetooth application and data can come and go at any time, any thread, thus the accuracy of instant data in local DB is critical on taking the right action.  However, the changes won't be taken if I don't commit it via `context.save()` right away.

To sum up, there are two questions here:

1. Why there are multiple `NSManagedObjectContextDidSave` triggered while `context.save()` are just called once?
2. While dealing with this kind of database structure (with lots of fields per record), is there any better model which can fulfill a better trade-off between UI experience and data accuracy?

By the way, To improve UI performance, I do use `NSFetchedResultsController` but find that it can do very little if my tables have relationships, so what I do is to put the most significant attributes in the main entity which NSFetchedResultsController fetches, however this doesn't help much as the main context is still busying merging.

My code on manipulating core data are written as follow:

```
// MARK: - Example on saving a NSManagedObject in background thread
class ExampleRepository : CoreDataStack {

    func updateRecordToDbInBackground(uuid: String, values: [String: Data]) {
        let ctx = getBackgroundContext()
        ctx.perform {
            guard let resultId = self.fetchByUuid(uuid: uuid, context: ctx) else {
                self.addRecordToDb(uuid: uuid, values: values, context: ctx)
                self.saveContext(context: ctx, method: #function)
                return
            }
            let result = ctx.object(with: resultId)
            _ = self.updateRecordToDb(uuid: uuid, values: values, managedObject: result, context: ctx)
            self.saveContext(context: ctx, method: #function)
        }
    }

    func fetchByUuid(uuid: String, context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> NSManagedObjectID? {

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: ENTITY_NAME)
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.uuid = %@", uuid)

        do {
            return try context.fetch(fetchRequest).first?.objectID
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
        return nil
    }

    func updateRecordToDb(uuid: String, values: [String: Data], managedObject: NSManagedObject?, context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> NSManagedObject {
        let registerObj = managedObject ?? getManagedObject(context: context)        
        registerObj.setValue(uuid, forKey: FIELD_NAME_UUID)
        let convertedValues: NSMutableDictionary = [:]
        values.forEach { e in
            convertedValues.addEntries(from: e.key: e.value])
        }
        registerObj.setValuesForKeys(convertedValues as! [String: Data])
        return registerObj
    }
    func addRecordToDb(uuid: String, values: [String: Data], managedObject: NSManagedObject?, context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> NSManagedObject {
        // add is generally similar to updateRecoredToDb, but adding some relationships to other entities
    }
}

// MARK: - Core data stack
class CoreDataStack {

    init(){
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.contextDidSaveContext), name: NSNotification.Name.NSManagedObjectContextDidSave, object: nil)
    }

    deinit{
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }
    var _context: NSManagedObjectContext {
        return SingletonContext.sharedInstance._context
    }
    var _backgroundContext: NSManagedObjectContext {
        return SingletonContext.sharedInstance._backgroundContext
    }

    func saveContext(context: NSManagedObjectContext, method: String) {
        guard context.hasChanges else {
            return
        }

        context.perform {
            do {
                try context.save()
                print("Context called from \(method) saved!")
            } catch let error as NSError  {
                print("Could not save context called from \(method), Error: \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }

    @objc func contextDidSaveContext(notification: NSNotification) {

        // The question is here: This func is called nine times when the context.save() were called once.

        let sender = notification.object as! NSManagedObjectContext

        if sender === self._context {
            print("******** Merge background context with main ********")
            self._backgroundContext.perform {
                self._backgroundContext.mergeChanges(fromContextDidSave: notification as Notification)
            }
        }
        else if sender === self._backgroundContext {
            print("******** main main context with background ********")
            self._context.perform {
                self._context.mergeChanges(fromContextDidSave: notification as Notification)
            }
        }
    }
}


class SingletonContext {
    static let sharedInstance = SingletonContext()

    var _persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator {
        return (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator
    }

    lazy var _context: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        let ctx = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.mainQueueConcurrencyType)
        ctx.persistentStoreCoordinator = self._persistentStoreCoordinator
        return ctx
    }()

    lazy var _backgroundContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        let ctx = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.privateQueueConcurrencyType)
        ctx.persistentStoreCoordinator = self._context.persistentStoreCoordinator
        return ctx
    }()

}
```

Comment: try checking if this way suits you https://softwarejuancarlos.com/2015/12/19/swift-2-examples-9-core-data-create-get-update-and-remove-entities/

Comment: The above link looks like just a basic tutorial, which didn't mention any efficiency issues about multiple context merging and issues with large number of fields.

Comment: I think that you should untie UI from DB data direct reliance. Because you have only 16ms for frame redraw, and db request can eat really much of it. If you need instant data, and can't delay UI refresh, you could, probably, do some memory caching of data while syncing it with db.